# Property call chain

Tags: python, attributes, call, chain

```
    class A:
        def run(self):
            ...

    class B:
        a=A()


    b=B()
    run=b.a.run
    run()
```

1:

```
(b.run == b.(B.__dict__['a']).run)
```

How can I get the method run here is called first by b?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: In the run here, check it to know that run.__self__ is a, then you can know that run is called by a, but a is called by b (b.(a.run)), what I mean is, how As you can know, run is called by b first

Comment: class A:
    def run(self):
        ...

class B:
    a=A()

class C:
    a=A()
b=B()
c=C()
run1=b.a.run
run2=c.a.run

def test(func):
    'func is b.a.run or is c.a.run?'

test(run1)